# Tet Pdf Text Extraction Tutorial

Tags: php, pdf, acrobat, text-extraction, pdflib

Does anyone know a good TET Tutorial, which is not the standard documentation?

The documentation provided by the homepage of pdflib isn´t that good, and I really need to understand how this works.

It´d also be okay when someone can explain me tet as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only the [standard documentation](http://www.pdflib.com/developer/technical-documentation/) for this but there is a mailing list on the pdflib homepage where you can post questions to other developers which are working with tet and pdflib.

Comment: Is there any Python tutorials? I only see for PHP and .NET